# Jquery Datatables - Seleccionar datos a través de una api pública

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, blade

estoy intentando montar una tabla dinámica con Jquery Datatables usando los datos públicos de una api, para ello tengo este código en el layout de blade

Aquí cargo los cdn de jquery y datables

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

En el formulario  tengo el siguiente código

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

<div class="container">

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
            "dataSrc": "",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "userId" },
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "title" },
                { "data": "completed" },
            ]
        } );
    } );

</script>

@endsection
```

El error que me da es este, y hace que no me cargue los datos de la tabla.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Hay una respuesta a esta cuestión en el sitio en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756179/3919660

Answer (score 2):

Para que te funcione debes dejar el código tal que así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", dataSrc:""}
            "dataSrc": "",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "userId" },
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "title" },
                { "data": "completed" },
            ]
        } );
    } );

</script>
```

Ya que te faltaba en el apartado "ajax" añadir dataSrc

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias. Me funcionó a la primera.

Comment: @MarkusMeridius si esto responde tu pregunta, por favor márcala como aceptada. Puedes leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para guiarte.